# image lookup alternative in MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In LLDB on Mac, one can check the compile unit from where a symbol is being picked up using

```
image lookup -vn A::~A
```

which dumps an output which contains something like

```
CompileUnit: id = {0x00000470}, file = "<path to file>/A.cpp", language = "c++14"
```

Is there an alternative in MSVC that helps obtain the same details? I'm fine if it's even a GUI-based approach in Visual Studio.